# Padding at Chakra UI

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I use Chakra UI and Next.js

```
<Box px={12} pt={10} bg={!isPc && "white"} pt={!isPc && "40px"} pr={!isPc && "12px"} pb={!isPc && "72px"} pl={!isPc && "12px"}>
```

this padding works but

```
<Box px={12} pt={10} bg={!isPc && "white"} p={!isPc && ["50px","12px", "12px", "50px"]}>
```

this padding doesn't work.

What is the differences?

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `array` then it works as responsive style instead to assigning property to `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left`.

So,

```
<Box width={[1, 1/2, 1/4]} />
```

is equivalent to

```
.Box {
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 30em) {
  .Box {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .Box {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```

[Official Docs](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/responsive-styles)